# gs960 no space between grids

Tags: css, 960.gs

i am using gs960 and want to create a container_12 that has two divs, one is grid_8 and the other is grid_4. Now, gs960 normally adds some margin between the two divs. In my design, i would like to have no space between those. I tried to use :

```
<div class='grid_8 alpha omega'>
</div>

<div class='grid_4 alpha omega'>
</div>
```

But it seems that the divs don't fill in 960px anymore and the last seems to be overlapping the first. Do you know how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this [generator](http://www.gridsystemgenerator.com/gs01.php) and set the margins to **0px**, ofcourse you can also do it in your .css file.

Comment: +1 for the answer. Thanks, that seems useful, but the problem is that i want to have both cases where there is the standard 10px and also a way to set 0px. Instead of creating a second variant, is there an easier way ?

Comment: it doesn't work, but i think editing the width of the grids may work. I will try it now